# Support needed for "butcher block" cart top?

Tags: tabletop, strength

Building a wheeled table or maybe better called a cart/bench that will slide back and forth over my washer and dryer. I can leave in place to fold on, or pull it out to have an additional table in the room to stack laundry on. Nothing heavy.

Only have room for legs / panels on the outsides, no room for an additional support between the washer and dryer. Intend to use 1.5 or 1.75 inch thick "butcher block" pre-made countertop out of rubberwood from Lowe's, which is not an end-grain butcher block. The grain runs lengthwise.

The legs will be 2-4s or 2x6s panels. My countertop will be 6 foot long and 33 inches deep. Overhang will be one inch on one side and zero on the other. So about 57 inches suspended wood between the legs.

I really don't want to build an apron under the countertop for support because I want to fold laundry on this and if the countertop gets any higher it will be hard to do that.

Can I build this in this way without the middle sagging down over time?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Just wanted to make a point of saying well done on recognising that this is "butcher block" and not the real thing.

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask, you up to speed on how to allow for seasonal expansion and contraction if your proposed design makes this necessary? Normally tables and cabinets have to allow for this because there's a cross-grain aspect to the way they are put together, your cart might not have this in which case it can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I build this in this way without the middle sagging down over time?

Yes. If the top were actual butcher block this would definitely require some additional support, but long-grain material like this (especially in this thickness) is more than capable of supporting its own weight over a span of 57", and quite a bit besides.

There isn't definitive data on the properties of rubberwood available online<sup>1</sup>, but even without extrapolating from similar hardwood species WoodBin's [Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) suggests there's nothing at all to worry about — as I usually do I plugged in some ludicrously OTT numbers to begin with, to see if there was potentially a problem, and, well, the computed sag was reassuring to say the least<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are conflicting numbers so you don't know what to trust.

<sup>2</sup> I typically walk back from some beyond-worst-case assumptions to more reasonable figures to see if the borderline/acceptable balance point lies within the hoped-for design parameters but here there was no need to. I started with double the total listed weight of the entire 72" panel, then added some more for good measure, selected central load and not uniform and *even with some ludicrously not-like-hevea substitutions* the amount of sag is so tiny it would be impossible to see even if you were looking for it!